# How to merge the separate list code into one?

Tags: python, list

```
lang_type=['ko','en','es','vi']

text_src = translator.translate(user_text).src
if text_src==lang_type[0]: 
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text) 
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text) 
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text) 

elif text_src==lang_type[1]:
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text)

elif text_src==lang_type[2]: 
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[3]).text)

else: 
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[0]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[1]).text)
    telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[2]).text)
```

When I try this code, it prints the separate message. I actually want them to be merged into one message.

I tried kind of [1:3] thing, but it didn't work

How can I make it happen? Please give some advice

cheers!

Comment: Use helper variables with clear names to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be much simplified by judicious use of a dictionary. I have no way of testing this but you should get the idea:

```
lang_type = {'ko': (1,2,3), 'en': (0,2,3), 'es': (0,1,3), 'vi': (0,1,2)}

msg = []

for i in lang_type[translator.translate(user_text).src]:
    msg.append(translator.translate(user_text, dest=lang_type[i]).text)

telegram.Bot(TelegramToken).send_message(user_id,'\n'.join(msg))
```